# How to replace text box value into property file using NSIS script?

Tags: nsis

I have created nsi file using NSIS plugin in eclipse.I have read the property file value using following code,

```
${ConfigWrite} "C:\resource\conf.properties" "WEBSERVICE.URL"  $0
```

Now i want to create one text box and copy the value of "WEBSERVICE.URL" into that textbox.If the user enter the input in textbox then it should replace the value of WEBSERVICE.URL in config property file.else it will take default value.can anyone hele me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the examples of [nsDialogs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html).

Look in the `Examples\nsDialogs` directory of your NSIS installation : the `InstallOptions.nsi` script should help you.

Comment: thanks.I have tried so far.but i cant move the property value textbox.can you have any idea?